# What is this "tracer" in The Peace War?

Tags: the-peace-war

From the chapter "Flash forward" in *The Peace War*, page 31:

> She recognized the smell that that still hung on her helmet: the tracer stench that tagged their landing fuel.

What is this "tracer that tagged their landing fuel"?